# NSPredicate with subclasses that have relationships Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm stuck with trying to create a NSPredicate for my data model that returns items when filtering by DetailedSpecification and Dimensions. I have searched forever and nothing I have found works. Any Swift answer will get me in the right direction, but I am using Xcode9 with Swift 4.
My base FetchRequest is :

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
```

I have 2 main questions on how to create the correct Predicate :

1. How to query against the attributes in DetailedSpecification Subclass of Specification (My attempts at using @class have failed)
2. How to also filter by attributes in the Dimensions Table, which is a many to one back to DetailedSpecification

[image: Here is an example data model for the issue I am having]

Comment: I assume the problem comes from the specs<->item relationship being on the parent entity, while the dimensions relationship and other attributes are on the child entity.  If you can move specs<->item to the child, I would do that.  If not, why not fetch DetailedSpecifications (using a predicate based on their attributes and the dimensions relationship), then use the to-one relationship to Item to get the corresponding Items?

Comment: Incidentally, I recommend you add an inverse for your dimensions relationship, even if you think it’s unnecessary and will never use it.  CoreData can do some weird things with one way relationships.

Comment: Perhaps I just need to change my data model.My idea was Item and Specification had attributes common to all objects in my app. Specifications had specs common to all objects. DetailedSpecification is where specifics to an object go. There is going to be more than one DetailedSpec table as the app grows for different objects. For example, if an item is a car, detailed spec would be CarSpecification, if its an Airplane, detailed spec would be an AirplaneSpecification with different attributes and perhaps different relationships. Maybe I need to just flatten the model to specific classes.